# script for running program 100 times and greping the result

Tags: bash

Im trying to write a script so that I can run my program 100 times and grep the execution time.
Currently I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [ $i -lt 100 ]
do
    (time -p ./mdu -j $i /pkg) &>> tempfile.txt
    echo $i
    let i=$i+1
done
cat tempfile.txt | grep real > plot.txt
```

However this does not give me the desired output. I wish to only get the execution time of the 100 runs but instead plot.txt comes out with 551 lines of data. All the lines does contain "real 1.31(random time)" but it feels like I get alot of duplicates or something.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote it, you append to `tempfile.txt` the resource use statistics, plus the standard and error outputs of your program. So if these last two streams contain `real` they will pollute your results. Try:

```sh
time (<your-program> &>> log.txt) &>> tempfile.txt
```

But why don't you use the `time` utility, instead of the bash builtin, and its options (`time -pao tempfile.txt`) to append only the statistics to your file? Something like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [ $i -lt 100 ]
do
    /usr/bin/time -pao tempfile.txt ./mdu -j $i /pkg &>> log.txt
    echo $i
    let i=$i+1
done
grep "real" tempfile.txt > plot.txt
```

Moreover, if you use the `time` utility you can even specify the output format, instead of using the `-p` POSIX format and grep the output. If, for your plot, it is more convenient to have only the real time value in [hours:]minutes:seconds:

```sh
/usr/bin/time -f'%E' -ao tempfile.txt ...
```

And if you want it in seconds:

```sh
/usr/bin/time -f'%e' -ao tempfile.txt ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I dont have to much experience with bash scripts and I am just trying to understand the correct way to go about with this. This made it clear why my data was so wierd. I will try with the built in time instead and figure out another way of appending the data!

Comment: Then use `time (<your-program> &>> log.txt) &>> tempfile.txt`, instead.

Comment: Ok, i rewrote the script with just a simple for loop containing your sugestion above, did the job as i wanted to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have 551 lines of data because you kept appending to `tempfile.txt` and never deleted its contents.

As a side note, your loop runs 99 times, not 100 times. Use either zero-based numbering or `<=`.

Last but not least, `time` is quite tricky (in its built-in form), especially due to the way it interacts with pipes.

```sh
run_n_times() {
  local -ir N="$1"
  shift
  local -ar args=("$@")
  local -i i
  for ((i = 1; i <= N; ++i)); do
    ( time -p "${args[@]//#/"$i"}"; ) \
    |& awk '/^real/ {print $2}'
  done
}

# A simple test:
run_n_times 3 sleep '#'

# The real thing:
run_n_times 100 ./mdu -j '#' /pkg
```